# How do I figure statistics for a skeleton or zombie I've animated?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

I have been trying to figure out how to animate dead. I understand that how many you can have with you at a time depends on your level and their HD, but I don't know how to determine their statistics.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is use human corpses to animate and just use the stats for a human zombie/skeleton straight out of the Monster Manual.

The Monster Manual also includes templates to apply to other creatures to turn them into zombies or skeletons, which is how you determine their stats.

Answer (score 1):

## 1. Determine the Kind of Corpse

Did you kill something? Did you find something already dead? Do you have some [Knowledge](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/skills/knowledge.htm) skills? Identify that corpse! Most of the time you'll get within 1-4 HD of identifying a corpse if you can identify the corpse at all. You don't want to accidentally use too much onyx gemstone when animating it. The corpse's Hit Dice provide a preview of how powerful a creature you'll be animating.

## 2. Cast [*Animate Dead*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/animateDead.htm)

If you've stuffed the corpse with sufficient onyx gemstones, the casting should make a skeleton or a zombie. Was the corpse fleshy? Then the corpse probably gets the template [**zombie**](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/zombie.htm). Was the corpse bony? Then the corpse probably gets the template [**skeleton**](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/skeleton.htm). If nothing happens, either too few onyx gemstones were stuffed into the corpse or the corpse wasn't an eligible target for the spell (e.g. it *wasn't* a corpse after all, it failed to meet the requirements for the template's application).

#### Determining the Creature's Statistics *Outside* the Game

Usually, it's the DM's duty to stat out monsters--even monsters the PCs make--because the DM plays all the game's NPCs, even ones under a PCs direct command. That means if the DM's saying *you* apply the template to a corpse, he should still provide some help. It's likely only he has the monster's original statistics anyway, which you'll need to apply the appropriate template.

#### Determining the Creature's Statistics *Inside* the Game

The character who animates the dead creature should have a decent idea of the creature's abilities. Assuming you're not in a hurry, you could order it to lift things to determine its strength, run to determine its speed, and so on. A successful Knowledge (religion) check should provide even more information about the creature you now control.